# Apache Solr: bitwise operations to filter search results

Tags: java, solr, drupal-7

I need to filter solr search results corresponding the access rights in our cms (drupal 7 + custom access control mechanism based on bitmasks).

There exists a Solr QParserPlugin plugin for search results filtering based on bitwise operations on integer fields: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1913.

I am using Solr 3.6.1 (+ the plugin in /var/lib/tomcat6/solr/lib/bitwise_filter_plugin.jar) on tomcat6 (on debian system) with the [schema.xml](http://drupalcode.org/project/search_api_solr.git/blob/3e6fda7:/solrconfig.xml) provided by the drupal module search_api_solr and the solrconfig.xml found in the modules issue queue (extended as indicated in the SOLR-1913 issue).

The Solr query ...

```
http://solr:8080/solr/select?qf=t_title&fl=*,score&fq={!bitwise field=is_bitmask op=AND source=1234}*
```

... fails with the following message in the error log:

```
Sep 27, 2012 8:57:41 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select params={qf=t_title&fl=*,score&fq={!bitwise+field%3Dis_bitmask+op%3DAND+source%3D1234}} status=500 QTime=15 
Sep 27, 2012 8:57:41 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.lucene.search.FilteredQuery.hashCode(FilteredQuery.java:268)
  at java.util.AbstractList.hashCode(AbstractList.java:542)
  at org.apache.solr.search.QueryResultKey.<init>(QueryResultKey.java:49)
  at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1084)
  at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:375)
  at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:394)
  at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:186)
  at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
  at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
  at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
  at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

The only thing I can see in the error message is that the plugin is invoked by solr.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Have you downloaded the jar and included it into your solrconfig.xml as the linked-to page suggests? You say you're using a version provided by Drupal module developers, hence the question.

Comment: Yes, I edited solrconfig.xml and placed the jar in the right place. The plugin is correctly included I guess otherwise it won't appear in the backtrace and solr would complain about not knowing the bitwise operator. ... I edited my question to make this more clear, thanks.

Comment: @kekkis: Do you think the query syntax is correct or am I missing something - regarding to [DisMax Parameters](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser)

Comment: Well, you are using `fq` while the example is using `q`. I would say try with q and see how it works.

Comment: The same here, it works for dismax: `http://solr:8080/solr/select?q={!dismax qf=is_bitmask}` but not for bitwise:
`http://solr:8080/solr/select?q={!bitwise field=is_bitmask op=AND source=1234}` ... same error.

Comment: Anything else I may check or can do to get it work?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of making Solr do it your way, you might want to try it Solr's way. Solr already implements boolean logic.

Split your bitfield into a set of named boolean fields. They can even be bit_0, bit_1, etc. if you are short on inspiration. You can use a dynamic field to save typing and allow later expansion.

Index them as bit_0:true and so on for each doc.

Use those fields in the filter query to do selection: bit_0:true AND bit_24:true.

This is likely to run much, much faster than a bitwise comparison on each field. The bitwise comparise probably needs a full table scan on each query. Well, full field value scan, since Solr does not have tables.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. This is also the way we finally did the implementation. We already have fields for each bit. For mysql query we are using bitwise comparison, so we thought it would be good to use it on solr too. While nobody was able to help on this issue we went the way you described above. Finally it seems to be a good workaround and maybe even more performant as you described. ... on the other side it does not answer the question on how to get the bitwise operator working.