# Solr index support for bit set?

Tags: solr

Solr is easy for indexing word based contents, but is there any support for bit set that,

- every bit is indexed separately (maybe)
- supporting querying them with multiple bit like bit operation in normal programming language
- the length of bits could be long, better that the indexing have no hard maximum length on it
- I don't mind representing the bits as string if have to but bit would be much more compact and may have better performance.

Where should I start with?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question. Very interested in knowing what you are accomplishing. Do you think you can use :                         <!-- boolean type: "true" or "false" -->
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/> or    <!--Binary data type. The data should be sent/retrieved in as Base64 encoded Strings -->
    <fieldtype name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>

Comment: Also  please post example documents, expected queries and results to better present your question.

Comment: Hi @Arun, I can't do that because the "tags" are not predefined (otherwise I need to change solr config every time I add the boolean field). The use case is simple, we're running an Ecommerce site that has a lot products which would be "attached" to 1-n campaigns, and we are about to use solr for speed up fetching product by campaign id/ids (like tagging) which is mapped to a bit of an integer array. However, using bit explicitly is not a must cos solr may have optimised that already. (one constraint is we're already using solr and won't going with something else.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is nothing built-in. There is activity within the community since October 2010 as you can see in [SOLR-1913](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1913). The attached plugin seems to work also, but it has not made its way into Solr's trunk, yet.

---

The other way I know and use is similar to the approach described in [Apache Solr: bitwise operations to filter search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636426/apache-solr-bitwise-operations-to-filter-search-results). I am using multivalued `string` or `int` types in my **schema**

```xml
<fields>
    <!-- other fields -->
    <field name="ints" type="int" 
        indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
    <field name="strings" type="string"
        indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
</fields>
```

To make use of this, translate your integer into a list of `Integer` or list of `String`, where each value of the list represents on bit position. If you need to hook this into a DataImportHandler, you can use [Solr's ScriptTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer).

```java
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(i);

for(int c = 0; c < binaryString.length(); c++) {
    if(binaryString.charAt(c) == '1') {
        integers.add(c);
        strings.add(c + "_1");
    } else {
        strings.add(c + "_0");
    }
}
```

as example `5` - which is `101` in binary - would become

- integers: [4, 1]
- strings: [4_1, 2_0, 1_1]

As you can see there is a difference: integers do not hold track which bits are absent whereas strings do. Which of these approaches suits your needs, depends on your use case. If you only need to know which bit is present, pick integers. This will make your index smaller. If you also need to know which bits are absent, pick strings.

To query for this is rather simple

- integers: `q=ints:(1 OR 4)`
- strings: `q=strings:(1_1 OR 4_1)`

If you want to exclude a certain bit, you would be tied to strings

- `strings:((1_1 OR 4_1) AND 2_0)`

---

A **caveat** of this way is that there is *maxBooleanClauses*. Most people do not know it, till they hit it. This defaults to 1024 clauses, which you can see [in Solr's Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#The_Query_Section). You may also alter it in your solrconfig.xml. But the bigger you set this value to be and the more clauses your queries have the slower Solr will get.

Up to now, we did not face performance issues with this. But we kept under 1024 clauses. This is something you should keep in mind, since I do not know how large your bit sets will be.

Comment: Great post, thanks!!! exactly what I want and I'm sure I haven't missed sth obviously.